# Refused to set unsafe header "Proxy-Authorization" Chrome

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron

Currently, I am developing a web application, that application needs to work with Proxy. When I am setting `Proxy-Authorization`. I am getting Refused to set unsafe header "Proxy-Authorization" Chrome error. Currently, I am struck badly. I am using an electron to build a desktop app. Any solution around electron

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

[image]

We're having the same problem. I'm using axios inside electron it seems that axios is trying to override the browser's headers and the browser prevents it to happen.

When I tried to make a request to http://ifconfig.me/all , the proxy and header I set did not take effect but when I run it on console only NodeJS (without ElectronJs), its fine.

My workaround solution is I used the built-in `http` module. It works but yeah I'm still looking for a Fix using axios.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using nginx as reverse proxy this might help:

I ran into this problem while using basic auth with authelia for API calls from axios. Authelia only supports `Proxy-Authorization` header.
My simple solution was to go on with the basic `Authorization` header and copy that header in the nginx authelia location like

```
location /authelia {
...
  proxy_set_header Proxy-Authorization $http_authorization;
...
}
```

Of course you can set your own header e.g. `Custom-Auth` and then `proxy_set_header Proxy-Authorization $http_custom_auth;`